# frame indicators for thmboxes in beamer

Tags: beamer, uncover, thmbox

I'm using beamer with the thmbox package to have nicely formatted lemmas/theorem/proofs. In particular, I'm using `\newtheorem` to define a few environments that I regularly use.
What I am missing is a way to tell beamer to uncover the environments at different frames conveniently (as is possible with the `block` environment):

```
\usepackage{thmbox}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem[style=M]{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{thm}<2-> % this is what I want to be able to communicate
    bla
  \end{thm}
\end{frame}
```

Is there any way to modify the environment to support this? I've been stuffing my theorems into `\uncover<2->{...}` but it feels like this isn't the way to go about it and I really want to avoid typing this many `\uncover`'s...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Thank you for including some code, it would be helpful to extend it into a small example that can compile though please, something like `\documentclass{beamer}` then include `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` with your code filled in. It helps people help you if they can compile and test solutions straight away :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a custom wrapper around your new theorems:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{thmbox}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem[style=M]{thm}{Theorem}

\newenvironment<>{mythm}{%
  \begin{actionenv}#1%
  \begin{thm}
}{
  \end{thm}
  \end{actionenv}
}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
  \begin{mythm}<2>
    bla
  \end{mythm}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: fantastic, `actionenv` is exactly the keyword I was missing, thanks :)

Comment: @igel You're welcome!